# Transform Dates in Dataframe Columns into New Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is a screenshot from Excel, but let's suppose we have a Pandas dataframe that looks like the table on the left where we have dates in a column. Is there an easy way to transform it into a dataframe that looks like the table on the right so that the dates become new columns?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot)

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Date', values='Candies')
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df
```

**Output:**

```
    Name  4/01/20  4/02/20  4/03/20  4/04/20  4/05/20  4/06/20  4/07/20   4/08/20  4/09/20  
0  Alice        1        2        3        4        5        6        7         8        9
1    Bob        2        4        2        4        3        2        1         3        0
```

Comment: I am getting `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` error. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Actually I fixied it! I used `pivot_table()` instead of `pivot`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the .xlsx as @victor proposed in above (change parameter as fits).

```
 df=pd.read_excel('my_excel.xlsx')
```

Group the data frame by the 'name' and 'date' columns and get the sum of the candles.

```
 df_grouped=df.groupby(['name','date'])['candles'].agg('sum').reset_index()
```

Now use '[pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table)' pandas method to pivot the grouped results.

```
 df_pivot=df_grouped.pivot_table('candles', 'name', 'date')
```

Comment: I actually wasn't trying to aggregate the data, but thank you still!